# Is there solr alternative without using xml or binnary

Tags: java, xml, solr, search-engine

I'm finding a full-text search framework to search my blog, i have seen solr [getting started](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html), but i find solr it's black-box framework, in my experience, if it raise some error, it will hard to debug and know what happen in its inner code.

so **my question is** is there java search framework that i can use it with pure java(without xml or bin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr is open-source, you can see it here http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

You normally would not need to debug it to begin with. Solr just wraps the Lucene engine in a REST API with a nice web interface so what would really your problem be?

If you want alternatives, nowadays the best/only alternative with lots of support would be elastic search, you can read more here http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/

Have a blast.